# why Linq GroupBy After OrderBy dismissed order operation?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a **Action** model with **Session** Navigation Property,

Consider this code:

```
var x=db.Actions.OrderBy(p => p.Session.Number).ThenBy(p => p.Date);//it's OK
```

x is a ordered Action, but when grouped on x, group not iterate on x(base on **Action.Session**) manually on ordered enumerable:

```
var y=x.GroupBy(p=>p.Session).ToArray()
```

y have a group(Key,IGrouping) of sessions but why group.Key **not ordered** base on **Session.Number**?

**How to i reached a group of Session order by number and each group ordered by date?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) that preserves order. No such promise is made for [`Queryable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492.aspx).
From the documentation of the former:

> The IGrouping(Of TKey, TElement) objects are yielded in an order based on
>   order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each
>   IGrouping(Of TKey, TElement). Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order
>   they appear in source.

You're calling the latter, and the above is not mentioned. Call `OrderBy` after `GroupBy` to make it work.

**Update**: since you apparently want to sort on more than just the GroupBy key, you should be able to use another GroupBy overload to specify that each session's list of actions is to be sorted:

```
db.Actions.GroupBy(
    p => p.Session,
    (session, actions) => new {
        Session = session,
        Actions = actions.OrderBy(p => p.Date)
    }).OrderBy(p => p.Session.Number).ToArray();
```

Comment: @RedHat I've updated by answer, but unfortunately I'm not able to check that this is supported by the provider right now. You can try it, or I will try it and update the answer as appropriate when I get the chance.

Comment: thanks @hvd for your note, your answer is good but i not find a overload of GroupBy method that accept (session, actions) =>..., also i answer question below.

Comment: I've managed to test it now (I was able to sooner than I had expected), and it does work here. If it doesn't for you, try calling `Queryable.GroupBy` explicitly: `Queryable.GroupBy(db.Actions, p => p.Session, (session, actions) => new { Session = session, Actions = actions.OrderBy(p => p.Date) }).OrderBy(p => p.Session.Number)).ToArray();` Generally, when an extension method isn't picked up by the compiler, and you know the extension method you want, explicitly calling that will let you know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not defined that GroupBy preserves either insertion order or the underlying key order (in the same way that `Dictionay<,>` makes no such guarantee, for local in-memory work). Just order after grouping, instead:

```
var y = db.Actions.GroupBy(p=>p.Session).OrderBy(grp => grp.Key).ToArray();
```

In particular, note that to translate the order directly would require it to analyse the expression to spot which parts of the ordering overlap with the grouping (and which don't), which is non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your note, i want to sort group key base on Session.Number and each group sorted by Action.Date, how to do that?i edit my question.

Comment: @RedHat for that, you could *try* putting the OrderBy(x => x.Date) on the first line, where the Number was

Answer (score 0):

Just the name `GroupBy` suggests that the data queried at that moment will be grouped, aggregated (call how you want) into another data unit based on  parameter provided.

In general if you want to see result `sorted` the `Sort()` function call should be the last one in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marc Gravell & @hvd for note about groupby IGrouping(Of TKey, TElement) not preserves order of TKey but preserves order of TElement.

So my answer for my final question **(How to i reached a group of Session order by number and each group ordered by date?)** is:

```
var x= db.Actions
.OrderBy(p => p.ActionDateTime)
.GroupBy(p => p.Session)
.OrderBy(q => q.Key.Number)
.ToArray();
```