# Linq to group record by multiple column and select first or default record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to group my table record by multiple column and try to get groups first rows record.Here is the Linq query.

```
var uploadAddedDate = from up in db.Uploads
                       where up.Url != null
                       orderby up.xxx, up.table1.TeamId
                       group up by new
                       {
                         up.AddedDate,
                         up.xxx,
                         up.table1.TeamId
                        } into upgrp
                        select upgrp;
```

I want to select each group first rows `AddedDate` attribute.

Comment: what is the expected behavior? what is actually happening? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get groups first rows AddedDate attribute from each group as it select whole group.

Comment: when you want to get the groups first AddedDate, why are you grouping by it? The AddedDate in each group will be unique this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var uploadAddedDate = from up in db.Uploads
                      where up.Url != null
                      orderby up.xxx, up.table1.TeamId
                      group up by new
                      {
                         up.AddedDate,
                         up.xxx,
                         up.table1.TeamId
                      } into upgrp
                      select upgrp.FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm not entirely sure now but I think after the `group by` there is not guarantee the groups are ordered, so this query would do the job:

```
var uploadAddedDate = from up in db.Uploads
                      where up.Url != null
                      group up by new
                      {
                         up.AddedDate,
                         up.xxx,
                         up.table1.TeamId
                      } into upgrp
                      select upgrp.OrderBy(e=>new{e.xxx, e.table1.TeamId}).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

If you want to select just one column (`AddedDate` in this case), you can use `let` clause as I show below:

```
var uploadAddedDate = from up in db.Uploads
                      where up.Url != null
                      group up by new
                      {
                         up.AddedDate,
                         up.xxx,
                         up.table1.TeamId
                      } into upgrp
                      let first=upgrp.OrderBy(e=>new{e.xxx, e.table1.TeamId}).FirstOrDefault()
                      select first.AddedDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment but I want to select only AddedDate in that query and in intellisense it not show any FirstOrDefault() function.

Comment: You should be able to call `FirstOrDefault`. `GroupBy` method returns  `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`, and that is one of the extension method defined to `IQueryable`

Comment: this post confirm my hunch about loosing the order:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644384/why-linq-groupby-after-orderby-dismissed-order-operation

Answer (score 0):

you could try this two linq query, the first get a simple collection of uploads element that are the first of each given group, the second get all uploads groups into each of whom there is only the first upload of the ordered list..

```
var uploadAddedDate = 
           (from up in db.Uploads
            where up.Url != null
            group up 
              by new{
                     up.AddedDate,
                     up.xxx,
                     up.table1.TeamId
                  } into upgrp
            select upgrp
           ).Select(upgrp => 
               upgrp.OrderBy(upelem => 
                 new { upelem.xxx, upelem.table1.TeamId})).First();  


var uploadAddedDateByGroup = 
           (from up in db.Uploads
            where up.Url != null
            group up 
              by new{
                     up.AddedDate,
                     up.xxx,
                     up.table1.TeamId
                  } into upgrp
            select upgrp
           ).OrderBy(upgrp => 
               upgrp.OrderBy(upelem => 
                 new { upelem.xxx, upelem.table1.TeamId})).First();
```

Comment: is there any feedback?